# JavaFX 2 -fx-effect breaks opacity

Tags: javafx-2

Has anyone else found that adding -fx-effect in a style prevents opacity working?

Here is a simple example

```
public class TestGUI extends Application {

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

    Line line = LineBuilder.create()
            .startX(150)
            .startY(0)
            .endX(150)
            .endY(250)
            .build();

    Button btn = ButtonBuilder.create()
            .text("Open countdown!")
            // this breaks the opacity!
            .style("-fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, grey, 5, 0.5, 2, 5);")
            .opacity(0.6)
            .build();

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Button clicked");
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(line, btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Test Application");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Take out the `style` clause and you can see the line through the button.

Is this a bug or am I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shadow is actually a shadow of the translucent node and translucent itself but because you are layering a translucent node on top of a tranlucent shadow, the overall result is still translucent, but much more opaque than if no shadow had been applied to the node.  Similar to layering two 50 percent opaque nodes.  The intersected area of the two layered nodes will be 75 percent opaque.

In your sample, you set the opacity to 0.6, so the combined opacity of the node + shadow is 0.6 + 0.4 * 0.6 = 0.84.  Plus the shadow is a darker color than the effected node to begin with.  This makes it difficult to see the line behind the effected node - but you can still just see it because the node + it's effect is not fully opaque.  To show what is going on more clearly, I set the opacity of your sample to 0.2, making the combined opacity 0.36.  You can see the result in the screenshot below where the line behind the effected node is still clearly visible.

[image: translucent effect]

Generally, shadows and opaque nodes visually don't mix and look all that good together

Comment: Great answer - thanks!  I was probably getting a little carried away with the aesthetics anyway but your're right, the two effects don't go together too well.  Most likely what I was imagining was the effect of having just the portion of the shadow you'd normally see i.e. I should draw a line bottom and RH side and blur that instead.